# Finding all collaborators and teams with organization repository access using github-script

Tags: github-actions, github-api, github-script

I am trying to create a report that will list all teams and individual collaborators to our organizational repositories. So far I have been able to generate an array that contains the list of repositories for an organization:

```
            const responses = await github.repos.listForOrg({ org: orgName })
            const responseData = responses.data
            for (const response of responseData) {
              const rURL = response.html_url
              const rName = response.name
              console.log(rURL)
              console.log(rName)
```

Eventually I want to add permissions to the report but I cannot get past the step to identify the teams/collaborators. What kind of javascript call/object can I reference to get to the collaborators and teams?

Comment: Have you tried the teams api? https://docs.github.com/en/rest/teams